# Is fetching data from a third party into EC2 considered Inbound Data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, inbound

We have a nightly cron job that will fetch a `2gb xml file` and then perform processing on it. Is this considered `inbound data` and thus is free under the new fee policy for Amazon EC2?

Comment: yes. this is called data ingress. Its not new. Ingress has always been free. Where you will end up incurring outbound charges is based on where you are storing the data and how you are processing it.

Answer (score 1):

In the *very* early days of AWS, there was apparently a charge for inbound traffic.

From [AWS Lowers its Pricing Again! – No Inbound Data Transfer Fees and Lower Outbound Data Transfer for All Services including Amazon CloudFront | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lowers-its-pricing-again-free-inbound-data-transfer-and-lower-outbound-data-transfer-for-all-ser/):

> Effective July 1, 2011, customers will not pay for any inbound data transfer.

Ever since that time, inbound (into AWS) data transfer has been zero charge.